# Cannot run ant for testing cocos2d-x samples

Tags: ant, cocos2d-iphone, cmd, cocos2d-x-3.0

When I write this

```
$ cd cocos2d-x/build
$ python ./android-build.py cpp-empty-test -p 20
```

it says

```
ant is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

however I have already set my environment variable ANT_ROOT to "D:\Mobile\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin"
and added it to PATH variable too.

what could be the issue?

I am using cocos2d-x-3.2.

Comment: Environment variable is called ANT_HOME (not ANT_ROOT). Also need to add "$ANT_HOME/bin" to the PATH variable so that "ant" command can be found.

Answer (score 0):

ANT_ROOT worked well for me. make sure you add the the variable in the system variables not for your user account and try version 1.9.5 that's the one that's worked for me